# Adding quantity to basket item is adding a new item

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am creating a basket and what I want is if an item that is already in the basket is added again, the quantity of the original item will be appended by 1.

Instead when I add an item that is already in the basket, a new item is added, and the quantity of this new item can be appended by clicking +1 on the original item.

**basket.php**

```
<?php
  foreach ($_SESSION["basket"] as $basketItemArray) {                   
?>

<form role="form" action="includes/functions/create_shopping_cart.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="basket-button" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $basketItemArray["item_id"]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <? echo $basketItemArray["quantity"]; ?>
    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

The above form sends the ***item_id*** through the value of the + button.

**create_shopping_cart.php**

```
$product_id = $_POST['basket-button'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE product_id='".$product_id."'";

$result = $connection->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if (empty($_SESSION["basket"])) {
    $_SESSION["basket"]  = array( 

    array( "item_id"=>$row['product_id'], "item_name"=>$row['name'],"quantity"=>1 , "price"=>$row['price']) );

} else {
    // There is already a basket to append to
    $current_basket = $_SESSION["basket"];

    $found = false;
    foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $product)
    {
        if($product_id == $product['item_id']) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($found)
    {
        $_SESSION['basket'][$product_id]['quantity'] ++;               
    } else {
        $new_basket  = array( 

        array( "item_id"=>$row['product_id'], "item_name"=>$row['name'],"quantity"=>1 , "price"=>$row['price']) );

        $_SESSION['basket'] = array_merge($current_basket, $new_basket);      
    } 
}
```

**Result**
[image: This is what the result of clicking the + button on the original item twice]

Comment: Did you check whether or not `$found` gets set to `true`?

Comment: Yes, $found is set to true when I try this

Comment: what happens when you remove the space before ++?

Comment: Did you also check the correct part of the if-loop is executed when $found is true?

Comment: Yes, the correct part is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not targeting/using the index of the products in basket.
Try this:

```
$product_id = $_POST['basket-button'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE product_id='".$product_id."'";

$result = $connection->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

if (empty($_SESSION["basket"])) {
    $_SESSION["basket"]  = array( 

    array( "item_id"=>$row['product_id'], "item_name"=>$row['name'],"quantity"=>1 , "price"=>$row['price']) );

} else {
    // There is already a basket to append to
    $current_basket = $_SESSION["basket"];

    $found = false;
    $id = '';
    foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key=>$product)
    {
        if($product_id == $product['item_id']) {
            $found = true;
            $id    = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($found)
    {
        $_SESSION['basket'][$id]['quantity']++;               
    } else {
        $new_basket  = array( 

        array( "item_id"=>$row['product_id'], "item_name"=>$row['name'],"quantity"=>1 , "price"=>$row['price']) );

        $_SESSION['basket'] = array_merge($current_basket, $new_basket);      
    } 
}
```

Your code can be optimized some more but for now it is more important to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you that worked but the only tweak I had to make was when appending quantity to the basket, the only argument needed was [$id] - [$product_id] stopped it working.

Comment: Okay, I changed that in the code. A better way for you to handle this whole system and get rid of the `foreach` is by using the product_id as a basket index. That way you can target it directly by checking `if (isset $_SESSION['basket'][$product_id])` and instead of using 'array_merge' you do '$_SESSION['basket'][$product_id] = $new_basket'